# Display MySQL count query result in a HTML table in php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

How to Display MySQL COUNT() query results in an HTML table in php. 

I used the following queries:

```
select name, count(*) from contacts group by 1 having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: put a for loop and just print you data.

Comment: check this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable

Answer (score 0):

Follow this example:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "select name, count(*) as total from contacts group by 1 having count(*) > 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) { ?>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Total</th> 
  </tr>
  <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?=$row['name'];?></td>
    <td><?=$row['total'];?></td> 
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>

<?php } else { echo "0 results"; } ?>
```

Comment: in laravel there more efficient way of using loop in view file and yes it will give him broad idea how to use loop or print his data in view file